# Parsing JSON data from my assets

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to parse JSON data from my assets, but my codes keep showing up error. I think I am doing something wrong.

chem_elements.json

```
{
    "Hydrogen": {
        "symbol" : "H",
        "atomic_number" : 1,
        "atomic_weight" : 1.00974
    },
    "Helium" : {
        "symbol" : "He",
        "atomic_number" : 2,
        "atomic_weight" : 4.002602
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ed.parsejson;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        parseJSONData();
    }

    public JSONObject parseJSONData() {
        String JSONString = null;
        JSONObject JSONObject = null;
        try {
            // Open the inputStream to the file
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("chem_elements.json");

            int sizeOfJSONFile = inputStream.available();

            // array that will store all the data
            byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeOfJSONFile];

            // reading data into the array from the file
            inputStream.read(bytes);

            // close the input stream
            inputStream.close();

            JSONString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
            JSONObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);

            // Get the JSON Object from the data
            JSONObject parent = this.parseJSONData();

            // This will store all the values inside "Hydrogen" in an element string
            String element = parent.getString("Hydrogen");

            // This will store "1" inside atomicnumber
            String atomicNumber = parent.getJSONObject("Hydrogen").getString("atomic_number");


            text.setText("element : " + element + " atomicNumber : " + atomicNumber);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (JSONException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return JSONObject;
    }

}
```

I am very new at this and I am trying to understand how does parsing JSON data works, please could anybody enlighten me on this matter ?
Thx in advance.

Error Stack

> 09-30 00:01:15.256  21598-21598/? D/Error﹕ ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 1251640
>   09-30 00:01:15.257  21598-21598/? E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1251724)
>   09-30 00:01:15.257  21598-21598/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ Error reporting crash
>       android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1251724 bytes
>               at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
>               at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
>               at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4425)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
>               at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
>               at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
>
> 09-30 00:01:15.163  21598-21598/com.example.ed.parsejson E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.ed.parsejson, PID: 21598
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 53 byte allocation with 627648 free bytes and 612KB until OOM; failed due to fragmentation (required continguous free 4096 bytes for a new buffer where largest contiguous free 0 bytes)
>               at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:114)
>               at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:350)
>               at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
>               at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:156)
>               at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)
>               at com.example.ed.parsejson.MainActivity.parseJSONData(MainActivity.java:51)
>               at com.example.ed.parsejson.MainActivity.parseJSONData(MainActivity.java:54)
>               at com.example.ed.parsejson.MainActivity.parseJSONData(MainActivity.java:54)
>               at com.example.ed.parsejson.MainActivity.parseJSONData(MainActivity.java:54)
>               at com.example.ed.parsejson.MainActivity.parseJSONData(MainActivity.java:54)
>               at com.example.ed.parsejson.MainActivity.parseJSONData(MainActivity.java:54)
>               at com.example.ed.parsejson.MainActivity.parseJSONData(MainActivity.java:54)
>               at com.example.ed.parsejson.MainActivity.parseJSONData(MainActivity.java:54)
>               at com.example.ed.parsejson.MainActivity.parseJSONData(MainActivity.java:54)
>               at com.example.ed.parsejson.MainActivity.parseJSONData(MainActivity.java:54)

Comment: there you go I have added the error stack. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `parseJSONData()` inside itself which cause a infinite recursive call:

> ```
>         JSONString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
>         JSONObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);
>
>         // Get the JSON Object from the data
>         JSONObject parent = this.parseJSONData(); // <-- this line
>
>         // This will store all the values inside "Hydrogen" in an element string
>         String element = parent.getString("Hydrogen");
> ```

Just delete that line and try again.

BTW, your `TextView text` is not initialized.

Comment: yup stupid me, got it, manage to parse the JSON data now. Thank you so much sir.